# Function with continuous derivative is continuous?

Tags: calculus, continuity

Is it true that if $\frac{d}{dx}f(x)$ is continuous, then  $f(x)$ is continuous too?

If not, can you give a counterexample?

Comment: Have you tried relating the definition of the derivative to the definition of continuity?

Comment: Do you mean the derivative in the sense of distributions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just the fact that your function $f(x)$ is differentiable is enough to prove that it is continuous. The derivative $\frac{d}{dx}f(x)$, need not even be continuous.
Please have a look here http://www-math.mit.edu/~djk/18_01/chapter02/proof04.html

Answer (score 5):

To be differentiable at a point $a$, a function [must](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function#Differentiability_and_continuity) also be continuous at that point $a$.  In your question, this holds for all $a\in \mathbb{R}$.